# object does not contain a definition for "Properties"

Tags: c#

I am getting an error

> An exception of type
>   'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in
>   System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'CategoryId'

below is my code

```
dynamic product = (from prod in EntityInitializer.inventoryContext.Products
                           join sCat in EntityInitializer.inventoryContext.SubCategories on prod.SubCatID equals sCat.SubCategoryId
                           join vat in EntityInitializer.inventoryContext.VATs on prod.VatID equals vat.VatId
                           where prod.ProdID == proid && !prod.IsDelete
                           select new
                           {
                               ProductId = prod.ProdID,
                               CategoryId = sCat.CategoryId,
                               SubCategoryID = prod.SubCatID,                               
                               ProdName = prod.ProdName,
                               Make = prod.Make,
                               Finish = prod.ProdFinish,
                               Price = prod.Price,
                               Vatid=prod.VatID,
                               VatValue=vat.VatValue,
                               Unit = prod.ProdUnit,
                               Width = prod.ProdWidth,
                               Depth = prod.ProdDepth,
                               Height = prod.ProdHeight,
                               Inch = prod.ProdInch,
                               ImageURL = prod.ProdImage
                           }).FirstOrDefault();
```

I want to retrieve **CategoryId** from **product** and product has contain all records which you can easily find in below attached image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6athN.png

**error image**
  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0rL.png

Comment: Surely you meant to type `prod.CategoryId` instead?  Otherwise you'll have to explain what "sCat" is supposed to mean.

Comment: @HansPassant please refere so it would be easy for understand.

Comment: @HansPassant "sCat " is alias of "SubCategory"

Comment: So when you step through your project you see `product.CategoryId` value is 10, as shown in your image, but when you hit the line of code that uses `product.CategoryId` it you get an exception? You should also include the code where the exception is thrown in your question.

Comment: @Clint please refer this link http://i.stack.imgur.com/ra0rL.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to access your property like this

```
product.GetType().GetProperty("CategoryId").GetValue(product, null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much you saved my time.